# WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x8007019e

Tags: windows, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed UBUNTU 18.04 LTS from Microsoft Store and getting this error.

I have seen many solutions but didn't worked for me!

~ In **windows features ON and OFF**, I have selected (checked) WSL which can't be checked and still getting the error.